# F-pseudosigma/pseudo standard deviation function in R

Tags: r, statistics, package

For an analysis I need to perform a "F-pseudosigma", also called the "pseudo standard deviation". I tried to look if it's in any R package, but can't find it myself.

There isn't much info on it to begin with.

Does any of you know a package that holds it, or if it is calculated in a function from a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit that I haven't heard about F-pseudo sigma (or pseudo sigma) before; but a bit of research suggests that it is simply defined as the [scaled difference between the third and first quartile](http://mkseo.pe.kr/stats/?p=5).

That can be easily translated into a custom R function

```
fpseudosig <- function(x) unname(diff(quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75)) / 1.35))
```

For example, let's generate some random data `x ~ N(0, 1)`

```
set.seed(2018)
x <- rnorm(100)
```

Then

```
fpseudosig(x)
#[1] 0.9703053
```

---

### References

(in no particular order)

- [Irwin, Exploratory Data Analysis for Beginners](http://irmaservices.nps.gov/datastore/v4/rest/DownloadFile/442981?accesstype=download): *"Instead of the using the standard deviation in an RSD calculation, one might consider using the sample-data deviation (F-pseudosigma). This is a nonparametric statistic analogous to the standard deviation that is calculated by using the 25th and 75th percentiles in a data set. It is resistant to the effect of extreme outliers."*
- https://bqs.usgs.gov/srs/SRS_Spr04/statrate.htm: *"The F-pseudosigma is calculated by dividing the fourth-spread (analogous to interquartile range) by 1.349; therefore the smaller the F-pseudosigma the more precise the determinations. The 1.349 value is derived from the number of standard deviations that encompasses 50% of the data."*
- http://mkseo.pe.kr/stats/?p=5: *"Simply put, given the first quartile H1 and the third quartile H3, pseudo sigma is (H3-H1)/1.35. Why? It’s because H1= μ – 0.675σ and H3 = μ + 0.675σ if X ∼N. Therefore, H3-H1=1.35σ, resulting in σ = (H3-H1)/1.35. We call H3-H1 as IQR(Inter Quartile Range)."*

Comment: Thank you, I guess this is less time consuming than trying to find a package that holds it! The reference of yours also gives another method to calculate (through MAD), I've got these values also.

Comment: @RoddyMacintyre No worries, glad it was useful. On a minor side note: Questions asking for R packages are explicitly off-topic around here; having said that, the definition of F-pseudo sigma seems to be so trivial that I'm not sure it would warrant an independent R package. Either way, good luck with your work:-)

Comment: PS. Out of curiosity: The reason why it is called *F*-pseudo sigma is elusive to me. I guess pseudo sigma may be F distributed. Perhaps somebody else can shed some light onto this.

Comment: It's kind of a naming convention mess I guess, because it's also mentioned as "sample-data deviation ". It is suggested as a possible non-parametric alternative to the relative stdev or coefficient of variation. Got the info from here: http://irmaservices.nps.gov/datastore/v4/rest/DownloadFile/442981?accesstype=download

Comment: @RoddyMacintyre Yes, it makes sense that it is "similar" to the sd but more robust. Still not sure on the F:-) A cursory look at the distribution of pseudo sigma based on 1000 random samples `x ~ N(0, 1)` suggests that it *could* be F-distributed. I imagine the degrees of freedom would be related to the sample size of `x` and the total number of samples.